# Idiomatic Rails way to put a micropost's textbox and submit button, avoiding the "render 'form'" scaffold code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've been trying Ruby + Rails today.

After creating the standard `User` and `Micropost` model, view and controllers, I wanted to add a page where one could, being an user, add a new micropost.

Up to the moment, as there's really no authentication going on, I'd be happy to have a page where one could get the user id via the url, having as only thing in the form a text box where one could type out the micropost to add to the site.

I've already wired up the routing needed:

```
match 'users/new_micropost/:user_id' => 'Users#new_micropost'
```

as well as the controller's code:

```
def new_micropost
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @micropost = Micropost.new #still not so sure about this
end
```

I've copy pasted `microposts/new.html.erb` file into a new file named `users/new_micropost.html.erb`:

```
<h1>New <%= @user.name %>'s micropost</h1> #added this thingy

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', users_path %>
```

What would be the best way to replace the idiomatic way to replace `<%= render 'form' %>` to only print a textbox asking me what's the micropost I want to post on the site plus a submit button?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the form simply create your own, passing in the `@micropost` variable, something like:

```
<%= form_for @micropost do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :body, :size => "60x12" %>
  <%= f.submit "Post" %>
<% end %>
```

Have a look at [these guides for more info](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html).
You might need to create a separate `create` action in your controller for this action.

Also, if you want the microposts to be associated to users you'll need to add the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :microposts, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Then you would change your new and create actions to something like:

```
def new_micropost
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @micropost = @user.microposts.build
end

def create_micropost
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @micropost = @user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
  if @micropost.save
    redirect_to some_path
  else
    render 'new_micropost'
  end
end
```

[Click here to read more about associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Note that you might have to update the form to submit to the correct controller: `<%= form_for @micropost, url: create_micropost_path(@user.id) do |f| %>`

Answer (score 1):

In Rails there are 7 standart actions of the controller , related with creating,reading,updating and deleting of the resource . It would be nice if you name your action `new` of the MicropostsController. You can use `form_for` tag to create a text area and a pair of buttons for submit and cancel . 
Example:

```
<%= form_for @micropost do |f| %>
   <%= f.label :content %>
   <%= f.text_area :content %>
   <%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

But the easiest way to learn in motion is to use Rails generators , like this :

```
rails generate scaffold Micropost content:text
```

Comment: I already used rails generator. Both User and Micropost were created that way.

Comment: Then you have a form generated on `localhost:3000/microposts/new` ?